# Start Winui 3 App from command line with arguments

Tags: windows, winui-3, msix, appxmanifest

My application is packaged and deployed using a local msix installer.
The installer works fine and the app runs fine.

For testing and maintenance scenarios, I need to be able to run the app from the terminal using extra command line arguments. The arguments are parsed in the `App.OnLaunched` handler  using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`.

The people using this maintenance mode are not software engineers nor IT specialists. What is the best way for me to instruct them how to run such mode?

More context:
After digging, I found that I could run the maintenance mode by running the exe from its obscure install location, for example:
`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\27984f1c-bb26-4e2b-b989-78304f1f716e_1.0.7.0_x64__45c2krxqwh2t0`

It looks like this install folder name follows a convention, the first part is an ID defined in the appxmanifest, then the package version, then the platform. Unfortunately, the last part (`45c2krxqwh2t0`) seems random.

I obviously cannot guess this folder location and copy it in the test protocol that I give the technicians for maintenance.

Comment: They should know powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier ! That is an excellent hint, I should be able to write a powershell script with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with thanks to [Simon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77542016/start-winui-3-app-from-command-line-with-arguments#comment136702322_77542016):

```
$installPath = (Get-AppxPackage -Name "my-app-id-from-appxmanifest" -AllUsers).InstallLocation
$exeName = "MyApp.exe"
$appCommand = ($installPath + "\" + $exeName)

Write-Host "Starting: $($appCommand)"
Start-Process -FilePath $appCommand -ArgumentList 'my-args-to-set-virtual-mode'
```